# Hermitian structure for complexes of vector bundles

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, derived-categories, chain-complexes

- Does it exist a different notion of Hermitian metric for complexes of vector bundles, besides the obvious data of a metric for each vector bundle?
- Same question for connections. In particular is there a generalization of the Chern connection for complexes of holomorphic vector bundles?

Thanks in advance.